# Git pulling older files on Amazon EC2

Tags: git, repository, amazon-web-services, versioning

Been using git for a few months now and this one has me stumped. We have a git repo on AWS EC2. Syncing is fine and works right out of the box using gitosis. The only issue we have is when you pull you sometimes get an older version of some files. My setup is like this:

[core]

```
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  ignorecase = true
```

[remote "origin"]

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@blahblahblah:/Project
```

[branch "master"]

```
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

git remote show origin

> - remote origin
>     Fetch URL: git@blahblahblah:/Project
>     Push  URL: git@blahblahblah:/Project
>     HEAD branch: master
>     Remote branch:
>
> > master tracked
> >     Local branch configured for 'git pull':
> >     master merges with remote master
> >     Local ref configured for 'git push':
> >     master pushes to master (up to date)

I work from my own branch, lets say mybranch and merge to the master. The strange thing is the latest files are present on the server as I can see them through gitk but it does not seem to pull the very latest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "git push" a branch to the origin repository you are updating the git repository but not the files on disk. You need to "git checkout " on the origin (EC2) repository in order to apply the repository to the local files.

Comment: Sorry i left that part out in my last section: i do checkout the the origin and then merge my branch and then push. I can see the files on the master branch but the really odd thing is older files get pulled which is what i do not understand.  

Just to clarify:     
 
-git checkout master    

-git pull      

-git merge mybranch    

-git push

Comment: To make sure I understand, you're running those commands on a client and not on the EC2 server. If so, to see your changes on the server's file system you need to log in to the server and "git checkout master".